# expose a referenced type (class) without need for additional reference

Tags: c#, dll, reference, layer

I have a layered system of .dlls between my application, where the lowest level has a class that provides certain functionality - an instance of this class can be received through a GetClass() function and then I can access its properties (basically, a collection of information of changing objects).

Now I noticed that when I want to access that information from the next higher level .dll, the compiler complains that I do not have the lower level .dll referenced (the one defining the class) - which actually I would want to avoid, to have a nice layered structure in my architecture.

How to get around this? Can I re-expose the referenced type? Do I really have to write a wrapper of my own, if I want exactly the same functionality? Or do I even need to reference the low level .dll again?

DLL 1:

```
class myClass;
myClass GetMyClass();
```

DLL 2:

```
myClass GetMyClass();
```

EXE:

How to access result from calling GetMyClass (DLL 2) without referencing DLL 1?

Comment: You'll need to load the assembly that contains the class at runtime in order to return the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems no way to achieve this, if `myClass` is defined in `dll1`, since objects of type `myClass` may be instantiated at runtime. To avoid this, you need to change the return type of `GetMyClass()` in `dll2` to return something defined in `dll2`. It can be a class quite similar to `myClass` and having the same properties (you can even use tools like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to easily convert between objects), but it definitely should be in `dll2`. Something like:

```
// dll1
class myClass
{
    ...
}

myClass GetMyClass()
{
    ...
}

// dll2
class myClass2
{
    public myClass2(myClass c)
    {
        // instantiate myClass2 with values from myClass
    }
}

myClass2 GetMyClass()
{
    // somehow get myClass and convert it to myClass2 here
}
```

Comment: Actually, I went for a similar solution.. as of now (later refactoring possible) I expose the functions from myClass as functions of dll2 (each time getting a myClass object). (Depending on how many those are finally going to be I might need to change the approach to something neater.)

Answer (score 4):

You need to separate all the common classes you use across all your layers into a new dll, then reference this dll on every project.

Try to use [interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173156.aspx) so you can work over the contract (the functionality) instead of the concrete implementation. It will help you to avoid unnecessary references.

```
// common dll
public interface IMyClass
{
    string MyData { get; set; }
    IMyClass GetMyClass();
}

// dll1
public class myClass : IMyClass
{
    public string MyData { get; set; }
    public IMyClass GetMyClass() { return new myClass() { MyData = "abc" }; }
}

// dll2
public class myClass2
{
    public IMyClass GetMyClass()
    {
         var c1 = new myClass();
         var c2 = c1.GetMyClass();
         return c2;
    }
}

// exe (references common and dll2)
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c1 = new myClass2();
        IMyClass c2 = c1.GetMyClass();
        Console.Writeline(c2.MyData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution! I forgot to say that I cannot change dll1 since it is external. Still, I keep your design in mind.. I am sure something similar will pop up again.

Comment: See also: [stairway pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29259414/stairway-pattern-implementation)

Answer (score 2):

We do something similar to this in our local code.  You can load the assembly at runtime, scan the types it contains using reflection, and again using reflection call functions and instantiate types from that dll, without ever referencing it directly in the project.

some of the key functions you will need are:

```
Assembly.LoadFrom(path); //get the assembly as a local object
Activator.CreateInstance(type); //create an instance of a type
Assembly.GetType(string);//fetch a type by name from the assembly
```

Once you have the type, basic reflection will give you pretty much every other piece you need.

Here is the snippet from my local code:

```
asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, filePath));

Type[] types = asm.GetTypes();
for (var x = 0; x < types.Length; x++)
{
    var interfaces = types[x].GetInterfaces();
    for (var y = 0; y < interfaces.Length; y++)
    {
        if (interfaces[y].Name.Equals("MyTypeName"))
        {
            isValidmod = true;
            var p = (IMyType)Activator.CreateInstance(types[x]);
                            //Other stuff
            }
    }
```

Also note: this is pretty old code now.  It has been neither reviewed nor refactored in years, so its essentially modern as of .NET 1.1, BUT: It illustrates the point.  How to load a type from a remote assembly that is NOT locally referenced.

Additionally, this is part of an engine that loads some 50 of these, given a rigid folder structure, which is why its so generic looking.  Take what you need from it.

Comment: The key thing to remember though, is that you DONT actually have the type definition locally, so EVERYTHING you do with it must be done via reflection...Properties, Methods, _everything_.  What our code has is a local interface that all our "modules" implement, so that we have something to handle them as locally without dealing with all the reflection code.  The modules in turn directly reference the high level interface so that they can implement it.

Comment: Thanks! Nice solution. Still.. I "dynamically reference" dll1, which in the end is rather similar. (I might have to do it though for another reason: different incompatible versions of the dll with different signatures to be selectively loaded depending on circumstances. Oh, dll1 is an external component, in case you wonder about such things..)

Answer (score 1):

The caller must have a reference to the class in DLL1 to know what type it is accessing. So yes you need to reference the first dll in the exe.  Since GetMyClass() returns a type in DLL1  the type needs to be exposed in the exe, therefore dll1 must be referenced.

Answer (score 1):

One solution here is to provide a 4th DLL that contains interfaces for your classes. You would reference this in all 3 of your layers, and return these interfaces instead of your classes.

This should give you a good idea of what I mean:

```
// DLL1
class ClassInDLL1 : IClassInDLL1
{
}

// DLL2
class ClassInDLL2
{
    public IClassInDLL1 GetClassInDLL1()
    {
        return new ClassInDLL1();
    }
}

// DLL3
class ClassInDLL3
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var dll2 = new ClassInDLL2();
        var dll1 = dll2.GetClassInDLL1(); // dll1 variable is of type IClassInDLL1

        // do stuff with dll1
    }
}

// interface DLL
interface IClassInDLL1
{
}
```

I'll be honest though, layering your architecture like this is usually not an awesome idea unless your project is really large. I find that artificially making assembly splits like this ahead of time can cause you unnecessary pain, not to mention the fact that you end up with 3-4 assemblies for a medium or small project that might only need 1.

Comment: Generally I suppose you are right. In this case, the lowest dll (dll1) is an external dll, so I cannot combine it, also, we need an additional layer (dll2) for advanced functionality shared for applications.

Answer (score 1):

I go with Nick using any Ioc framework like spring.net or microsoft unity. to get the idea properly go through http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html